# Equilateral triangle ABC has side points M, D and E. Given AM = MB and $\angle$ DME $=60^o$, prove AD + BE = DE + $\frac{1}{2}$AB

Tags: geometry, triangles

I would like to ask if someone could help me with solving the following probelm.

The triangle $ABC$ is equilateral. $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$. The points $D$ and $E$ are on the sides $CA$ and $CB$, respectively, such that $\angle DME=60^o$

[image]

Prove that $AD+BE = DE + \frac{1}{2}AB$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please multiply by $e^{i\pi/2}$ your image? ;) Just kidding, I mean rotate 90º

Comment: I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Well, open the image with any decent application, rotate it and edit your question to change the image.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your thought process?

Comment: I found, that triangle AMD and MBE are similar.

Comment: Bro assign coordinates and bash!!!! Not that cosine law isn't coordinates in disguise, but still.

Comment: Since you started with a similarity of two triangles, you're very close to a solution without coordinates and trigonometry. See my proposal if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A nice path without trigonometry**

Consider the Figure below, where point $F$ has been taken so that $DF \cong DE$, point $L$ so that $BL \cong BE$, and point $G$ so that $AG\cong AF$.

[image]

1. $\angle AMD \cong \angle MEB$, because they are both supplementary to $\angle EMB + 60^\circ$.
2. Conclude therefore that $\triangle ADM \sim \triangle EMB$. In particular we have that $\frac{DM}{EM}=\frac{AM}{EB}$.
3. From the latter proportionality, the congruence $AM\cong MB$, and SAS cryterion, conclude that $\triangle DEM \sim \triangle ADM$, and in particular $\angle ADM \cong\angle MDE$.
4. Hence, by SAS cryterion, $\triangle DFM \cong\triangle DEM$, and in particular $FM\cong ME$, and $\angle FMD \cong \angle DME = 60^\circ$.
5. Use the latter congruences plus the fact $\angle FGM \cong \angle MLE = 120^\circ$ and $\angle GFM \cong \angle EMB$ (why?), to show that $\triangle FGM \cong \triangle EML$.
6. The thesis follows from the fact that $AD-DE\cong AF \cong AG \cong ML\cong MB-LB \cong MB-BE$.

Comment: @AkshajBansal, thanks for the appreciation. I guess practice helps considerably: working with lots of first and second year high school students, that must solve these kind of problems without trigonometry (which they only deal with in their third or fourth year, here in Italy) I always search with them for the most "basic" path. 

As far as a possible approach is concerned: when dealing with congruences of sums/differences of segments, I suggest to construct (with the mimimum  strictly necessary additional points) triangles having sides directly equal to those sums or differences.

Comment: How do you come up with such constructions and elegant solutions is it because of practise or there is a method to do these type of questions !? (+1 indeed)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @dfnu

Answer (score 0):

To simplify, assume all lengths relative to $|AM|$. In other words, $AM=1$

Let $x = CD, \quad y = CE,\quad z=DE$

Assume the statement to be proved is true, this follows:

$AD + BE = (2-x)+(2-y) = z + 1 \quad → x+y+z=3$

$ΔCDE:\; z^2 = x^2 + y^2 - x y$

$$(3-x-y)^2 = x^2+y^2-xy$$
$$x^2+y^2+2xy-6(x+y)+9 = x^2+y^2-xy$$
$$3xy - 6(x+y) + 9 = 0$$
$$xy - 2(x+y) + 3 = 0$$

Let $T = xy-2(x+y)+3$. If $T=0$, we proved $AD+BE=DE+{1\over2}AB$

---

**Laws of Cosines:**

$ΔADM:\; DM^2 = 1 + (2-x)^2 - (2-x) = x^2-3x+3$
$ΔBEM:\; EM^2 = 1 + (2-y)^2 - (2-y) = y^2-3y+3$

$ΔDEM:\; z^2 = x^2+y^2-xy = DM^2 + EM^2 - DM·EM$

$$DM·EM = xy-3(x+y)+6 = T+(3-(x+y))$$
$$(DM·EM)^2 = (T+(3-(x+y)))^2$$
$$T^2 + (x+y)T + z^2 = T^2+2(3-(x+y))T+(3T+z^2) $$
$$3(x+y-3)\;T = 0$$

---

All is left is to show $(x+y-3)$ is non-zero.
If $x+y=3$, we have $DM·EM = xy - 3(x+y) + 6 = xy-3$

Using AGM inequality $\large \sqrt{xy} ≤ {x+y \over 2} = 1.5$
This implied $DM·EM ≤ 1.5^2 - 3 < 0$, thus $x+y≠3$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ be the side length of the equilateral triangle ABC. Apply the cosine rule to the triangle CDE,

$$DE^2 = (a-AD)^2+(a-BE)^2-(a-AD)(a-BE)$$
$$= \left(AD + BE -\frac a2\right)^2 + 3\left(\frac {a^2}{4} -AD\cdot BE \right)\tag{1}$$

Now, recognize $\angle DMB = 60 + \angle ADM$ to conclude $\angle EMB = \angle ADM$ and, likewise, $\angle DMA = \angle MEB$. Thus, the triangles ADM and BEM are similar, which yields,

$$AD\cdot BE = AM\cdot BM = \frac 14 a^2$$

As a result, (1) simplifies to $ DE^2= \left(AD + BE -\frac a2\right)^2$, which is,

$$AD+BE = DE + \frac{1}{2}AB$$

Comment: Thank you very much. :)